# How do I write codes to calculate the following averages in an array?

Tags: r, arrays

Apologies if this is too simple. I have been looking but not able to solve it.

Dimensions of my data looks like this

y is [1:267, 1:3, 1:10]

It basically represents 267 sites, 3 surveys every year for 10 years. Whole data is in 0s and 1s

I want to get two different values.

Temporal value

1. average of each year. Basically, sum of values of 267 sites/ 267*3
   The outcome I am expecting should be 10 values for 10 different years.

Spatial

2. average of all years and surveys at 267 sites.
   The outcome I am expecting should be 267 values for 267 sites.

This is how I created my array.

```
y <- array(NA, dim=c(nsite, nsurvey, nyear))
date <- array(NA, dim=c(nsite, nsurvey, nyear))
for (t in 1:nyear) {
  for (j in 1:nsurvey) {
    y[,j,t] <- detect[,3*t-3+j]; date[,j,t] <- dates[,3*t-3+j]
  }
}
```

I am trying to write this code in R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't particularly recommend doing this with pure arrays, as opposed to using long-format data frames with column names or similar. But you can if you wish. Rather than loop over your array you can use `apply()` and related functions to get the statistics you want out of it. For example, something like this:

```r
# Make reproducible
set.seed(1622)

# Dims
nyear <- 10
nsurvey <- 3
nsite <- 267

# Generate some 0/1 observations
n <- nyear * nsurvey * nsite
vals <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)

# Make the array and name the dimensions
y <- array(vals, 
           dim=c(nsite, nsurvey, nyear), 
           dimnames = list(site = 1:nsite, 
                           survey = 1:nsurvey,
                           year = 1:nyear))

dim(y)
#> [1] 267   3  10

# Site 1
y[1,,]
#>       year
#> survey 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>      1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0  1
#>      2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1  0
#>      3 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1  1

# Site 200
y[200,,]
#>       year
#> survey 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
#>      1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1  1
#>      2 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0  1
#>      3 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1  1

# Sites 1:5, Year 1
y[1:5,,1]
#>     survey
#> site 1 2 3
#>    1 0 1 1
#>    2 0 0 0
#>    3 1 1 1
#>    4 0 0 0
#>    5 1 0 1

# Site 1, Survey 1
y[1,1,]
#>  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
#>  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  1  0  1


## Average of all sites and surveys by year
apply(y, "year", mean)
#>         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
#> 0.5106117 0.5243446 0.4794007 0.4968789 0.4968789 0.5168539 0.4818976 0.4881398 
#>         9        10 
#> 0.5230961 0.5156055

## Average of all years and surveys by site
## Just show the first 10 sites
out <- apply(y, "site", mean)
length(out)
#> [1] 267
out[1:10]
#>         1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8 
#> 0.4333333 0.3666667 0.6000000 0.3666667 0.4666667 0.3333333 0.6333333 0.5666667 
#>         9        10 
#> 0.4666667 0.6333333

## You can also do eg
round(apply(y, c("survey", "year"), mean),2)
#>       year
#> survey    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
#>      1 0.52 0.52 0.51 0.53 0.50 0.54 0.50 0.51 0.50 0.57
#>      2 0.50 0.54 0.46 0.48 0.48 0.50 0.49 0.47 0.53 0.50
#>      3 0.51 0.51 0.48 0.48 0.51 0.51 0.46 0.48 0.54 0.48
```